# Devise and multiple users models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I'm fairly new to `Rails` and trying to setup an app that uses several types of users: `Teacher`, `Student`, `Admin` (and likely more to come).

The reason I want different models is because the attributes for the various users differ. For example, `Teacher` have topics taught, a profession, and a diploma. Whereas `Student` and `Admin` do not. Students can leave reviews of teachers, etc.

I thought of having a general `User` model for the general information such as *name*, *email*, and other contact information and each type of user would inherit of it:

```
class Admin < User
end

class Teacher < User
end

class Student < User
end
```

And so on.

I'm using `Devise` for authentication and used `STI` for differentiating between user roles through a role field in the table.

The thing is, where and how can I tell my app to generate a `current_user` of the right class when the user logs in? And where should I store the additional info on each model (ex the profession of a teacher). In the users table?

About the relationship with their objects, for example, a teacher has many topics he teaches. How can I make sure only teachers have topics and not students?

I've looked into [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) but was utterly confused.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is : DONT DO THAT ! You are mixing very different concerns and will end up with the infamous God Object.

User is here only for authentication, you should not mix it with your domain models. Teacher / Student / Admin etc should be separate models from User. You can eventually create a People table and have Teacher Student and Admin inherit from it.

```
class Student < Person
```

Or have a different table for each of them so there's no possible confusion (also someone might be both a Teacher and an Admin for example, separating stuff keeps your options open)

But whatever you choose keep User out of it !

If you want to tie a User to Teacher / Student / Admin use associations and give each of them a user_id.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: So if I get it right, you suggest I link a user model to a student (for example). With the user holding all the connexion info and the student all the personal informations (name etc).
In that workflow, when / how do I create the student object associated with the logging in user ?
What if a user changes status (from Student to Teacher, or to Admin) ?

Comment: automatically creating an association can be done in many ways and is common, but too long to answer in a comment (e.g. using a `before_create` action) . Regarding the 2nd question I'm sorry to say it depends. But you can use STI (aka Student < Person; Teacher < Person) for one since you just need to change the type column to change someone's status...

Comment: This is great advice. I was about to use the User table as defacto students table

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into this link. Hope this may helpful to  you:-

```
http://funonrails.com/2011/12/multiple-resources-registrations-with/
```

Also, you can manage relationship with their objects by making model(table) as polymorphic like:-

```
# Topic Model:
belongs_to :readable, :polymorphic => true

Also in topic model there are two more fields:-
readable_id and readable_type.

# Teacher Model:
has_many :topics, as: :readable

# Sturdent Model:
has_many :topics, as: :readable
```